# Getting SQL table name from jTextField Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I want to know if there is a way to get my database table name that was entered into a JTextField named **jTextField1**. When I try:

```
String sqlc = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database." +jTextField1.getText()...
```

It simply doesn't work, and it throws a syntax error. It'll work on a LAN network only. This is my full **Create Table** SQL string:

```
String sqlc = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database." +jTextField1.getText() +
"(IDKath INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," +"ΕΣΟΔΑ DOUBLE NULL," +
"ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ DATE NULL," +"IDClea INT(11) NULL," +"PRIMARY KEY (IDKath)," +
"INDEX IDClea_idx (IDClea ASC)," +"CONSTRAINT IDClea" +"FOREIGN KEY (IDClea)" +
" REFERENCES database.cleaning (IDClean)" +" ON DELETE NO ACTION" +" ON UPDATE NO ACTION)";
```

Comment: Do you really want to build a big entrance for SQL injection?

Comment: Did you inspect the combined string to make sure it contains what you think it does?  Beyond that, more detail (at least the full line with the create table command from Java) will be needed to answer.

Comment: What is the message of the exception? Add the stacktrace

Comment: It ll work on a lan network only.   String sqlc = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database`." +jTextField1.getText()
  +"(`IDKath` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
  +"`ΕΣΟΔΑ` DOUBLE NULL,"
  +"`ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ` DATE NULL,"
  +"`IDClea` INT(11) NULL,"
  +"PRIMARY KEY (`IDKath`),"
  +"INDEX `IDClea_idx` (`IDClea` ASC),"
  +"CONSTRAINT `IDClea`"
    +"FOREIGN KEY (`IDClea`)"
   +" REFERENCES `database`.`cleaning` (`IDClean`)"
   +" ON DELETE NO ACTION"
   +" ON UPDATE NO ACTION)";

Comment: It throws a syntax error saying '.(whatever value i write in textfield)('IDKATH' INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'ΕΣΟΔΑ' DOUBLE NULL, 'HMER' at line 1. line 1 is this: "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database`." +jTextField1.getText()

Answer (score 0):

First thought...is **database** actually the name of the database you are trying to create the table in?

Second thought, does the table already exist within the database?

Third thought, does **jTextField1.getText();** actually give you anything or giving you what you expect it to? Test for that:

```
System.out.println(jTextField1.getText());
```

Just for the heck of it, try this SQL string:

```
String sqlc = "CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] database." + jTextField1.getText() + 
              " (IDKath INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ΕΣΟΔΑ DOUBLE [DEFAULT NULL]," +
              " ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ DATE [DEFAULT NULL], IDClea INT(11) [DEFAULT NULL]," + 
              " PRIMARY KEY (IDKath), INDEX IDClea_idx (IDClea ASC)," + " [CONSTRAINT [IDClea]]" +
              " FOREIGN KEY [IDClea_idx] (IDClea)" + " REFERENCES database.cleaning (IDClean)" +
              " [ON DELETE NO ACTION] [ON UPDATE NO ACTION])Engine=InnoDB;";
```

Comment: 1) database realy is the name of the database
2) added System.out, it prints the value of jTextField1
3) Doesnt work, syntax error near [IF NOT EXISTS]...

I think the problem is i cant actually name the table "dynamically" by using a method. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem dynamically naming the table you want to create like you're doing it unless of course the name has whitespaces in it in which case enclose it in square brackets:  `CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [database." + jTextField1.getText() + 
              "] (IDKath INT(11).......`. Is this indeed for the **MySQL** database platform?

Comment: It doesnt have any whitespaces :/... What do you mean by "this"?